# Disable dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code -

```
var obj = $('[id$=ddlInsert4]')
obj.disable = true;
```

obj is a drop down list, but the disable call doesn't disable the drop down list.

```
alert(obj.val()) //this returns the correct value
```

Since my alert is returning the correct value, I know my jQuery syntax is correct.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element.  You need to do `$(obj).prop('disabled', true);`.  Or better yet, if you don't need the `obj` variable elsewhere, just do:

```
$('[id$=ddlInsert4]').prop('disabled', true)
```

To interact with native DOM elements, you can do `[0]` (or `.get(0)`).  Then you can do:

```
obj[0].disabled = true;
```

(note that the property is `disabled` not `disable`)

Note: `$('[id$=ddlInsert4]')` can return multiple elements, and `[0]` will just get the first one.  You'd need to loop over all of them, if there were more than one.  I suggest using the jQuery `.prop` method though, as it will loop over all the elements for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `.prop` like below,

```
$('[id$=ddlInsert4]').prop('disabled', true);
```

You can use jQuery `.prop` function like above

or

`$('[id$=ddlInsert4]')` returns a jquery object (selector always returns array of jQuery object) so You cannot set DOM properties on jQuery object like that..

You need to iterate in a loop and set the property ex: `$('[id$=ddlInsert4]')[i].disabled = true` where `i` is the index.